# How to subtract two columns in different table

Tags: sql

I have a table of ward

```
ward_number | class | capacity
________________________________________
1           | A1    | 1
2           | A1    | 2
3           | B1    | 3
4           | C     | 4
5           | B2    | 5
```

*capacity = how many beds there is in the ward*

I also have a table called ward_stay:

```
ward_number | from_date   | to_date
_____________________________________________
2           | 2015-01-01  | 2015-03-08
3           | 2015-01-16  | 2015-02-18
6           | 2015-03-05  | 2015-03-18
3           | 2015-04-15  | 2015-04-20
1           | 2015-05-19  | 2015-05-30
```

I want to count the number of beds available in ward with class 'B1' on date '2015-04-15':

```
ward_number  | count 
_____________________
  3          | 2
```

How to get the count is basically capacity - the number of times ward_number 3 appears

I managed to get the number of times ward_number 3 appears but I don't know how to subtract capacity from this result.

Here's my code:

```
select count(ward_number) AS 'result'
from ward_stay
where ward_number = (select ward_number
                     from ward 
                     where class = 'B1');
```

How do I subtract capacity from this result?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? (`AS 'result'` is invalid SQL)

Comment: On 2015-05-19, B1 wards have three beds available.  How are you getting a value of "1"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff `Capacity` refers to how many beds the ward can hold. Since `ward_number` in ward_stay table appeared 2 times (so 2 patients are already in this ward, thus, 2 beds are used), I get the value '1'.

Comment: @Minchae Ward 3 are used but in a different dates, not `2015-05-19`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Oh right sorry my mistake.. but what if 2 of the beds in ward 3 are used on that date? How do I substract the `capacity` from the result i've obtained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select w.ward_number,
   w.capacity - count(ws.ward_number) AS "result" 
from ward as w left join ward_stay as ws 
on ws.ward_number = w.ward_number
and date '2015-05-19' between ws.from_date and ws.to_date
where w.class = 'B1' -- which class
     -- bed not occupied on that date
group by w.ward_number, w.capacity
having w.capacity - count(*) > 0 -- only available wards
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7053e/1)

Comment: probably need `left join` for when all beds are free.

Comment: I tried inserting a date for when all beds are free, however no results were displayed. (even with `left join`) any idea why? but the correct results were displayed though when not all beds are free

Comment: @Minchae: The condition on the date must be moved to `ON`, now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2ab55/12)**

Using `2015-01-17` instead I calculate the total of `occupied` bed on that day. Then join back to substract from original `capacity`. in case all bed are free the `LEFT JOIN` will return `NULL`, so `COALESCE` will put `0`

```
SELECT w."ward_number", "capacity" - COALESCE(occupied, 0) as "count"
FROM wards w
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT "ward_number", COUNT(*) occupied
      FROM ward_stay
      WHERE to_date('2015-01-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN "from_date" and "to_date"
      GROUP BY "ward_number"
     ) o     
  ON w."ward_number" = o."ward_number"
WHERE w."class" = 'B1'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ward_number | count |
|-------------|-------|
|           3 |     2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate *both* tables before returning, because you have multiple rows for the same word type in both.  So:

```
select c.class, (c.capacity - coalesce(wc.occupied)) as available
from (select class, sum(capacity) as capacity
      from ward
      group by class
     ) c left join
     (select w.class, count(*) as occupied
      from ward_stay ws join
           ward s
      on ws.ward_number = w.ward_number and
         '2015-05-19' between ws.from_date and ws.to_date
     ) wc
     on w.class = wc.class;
```

Note:  this is standard SQL except for the date constant.  This works in most databases; some might have other formats (or it might depend on internationalization settings).

Strictly speaking the aggregation on `ward` is not necessary for "B1".  But it is clearly necessary for "A1".